# NSFetchRequest (Swift3)

Tags: xcode, coredata, swift3

Изменился NSFetchRequest
Теперь все происходить примерно так

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Level> = Level.fetchRequest
```

Но потом началось самое интересное.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  let request: NSFetchRequest<Level> = Level.fetchRequest
} else {
  let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Level") as NSFetchRequest!
}
```

И все бы хорошо, но ведь `request` нужен за пределами `if/else`

```
try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

> Вопрос, как сделать `request` учитывая `is/else` ?

P.S. Инициализация перед `if/esle` не работает, т.к. инициализация для них разная. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.S писать `try context.fetch(fetchRequest)` отддельно для каждой оси - глупо!

Comment: а просто объявить за if/else а инит уже сделать внутри не получится?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko не получается

Comment: а что именно пишет, если объявлять заранее?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko

var fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<AnyObject>! Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  fetchRequest = MapPoint.fetchRequest()
} else {
  fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MapPoint")
}
```

> Вот это уже выглядит как приемлемый вариант, пользуйтесь!